# AngularJS redirecting to another module

Tags: angularjs, restful-authentication

my problem is a simple redirect after login in a angularjs controller.

```
function LoginController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, $cookieStore, LoginService) {
$scope.login = function() {
    LoginService.authenticate($.param({username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()}), function(user) {
        $rootScope.user = user;
        $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Token'] = user.token;
        $cookieStore.put('user', user);
        $location.path("/secure/");
    });
};
```

};

I don't have the path /secure in my ng-app. Infact, I have to redirect to another ng-app.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: IndexController
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/price', {
            templateUrl: 'price.html'           
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'signup.html'
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'signin.html',
            controller: LoginController
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/features', {
            templateUrl: 'features.html'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'         
        });
```

What do you think?

Comment: maybe you should use $location.url instead and redirect to an absolute URL

Comment: what is the meaning of another ng-app is it seperate app or differenct page in your app